# Simulation of decoders on LTSpice

Tags: simulation, ltspice, spice

I need to simulate a 2:4 decoder on LTSpice however the component does not exist. Does anyone know of a way to simulate it?

Comment: Create the component.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question: you want to *simulate* in LTspice a decoder, yet you ask for `a way to simulate it`?